# How do I pass a list of integers to an MVC action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Can i use List  or something?

Comment: How are you intending to pass the list? from a client call (javascript) or from a view page?

Comment: +1 for shortest question I've seen on this site. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Scott Hanselman has an excellent tutorial for doing this [**here.**](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx)

Comment: Phil Haack has an updated version, with a download project. http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Answer (score 13):

You need to pass them to your action via adding each integer to your POST or GET querystring like so:

```
myints=1&myints=4&myints=6
```

Then in your action you will have the following action

```
public ActionResult Blah(List<int> myints)
```

MVC will then populate the list with 1,4, and 6

One thing to be aware of.  Your query string CANNOT have brackets in them.  Sometimes when the javascript lists are formed your query string will look like this:

```
myints[]=1&myints[]=4&myints[]=6
```

This will cause your List to be null (or have a count of zero).  The brackets must not be there for MVC to bind your model correctly.

Comment: Definitely not working for me. Just getting a big fat `null` for the `List<string>` object.

Comment: @jpmc26 for me, it worked. Perhaps one of values at the client side is a Javascript's `null` ?

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to send the list from some interface item (like, a table), you can just set their name attribute in the HTML to: CollectionName[Index]
for example:

```
<input id="IntList_0_" name="IntList[0]" type="text" value="1" />
<input id="IntList_1_" name="IntList[1]" type="text" value="2" />
```

And

```
public ActionResult DoSomething(List<int> IntList) {
}
```

The IntList parameter wil receive a list containing 1 and 2 in that order

Answer (score 1):

Just take the right sort of collection. Exactly which sort depends on which version:

MVC1 : `public ActionResult DoSomething(int[] input)`
MVC2 : `public ActionResult DoSomething(IList<int> input)`

Comment: You can pass a `List<int>` into an action method in MVC 1.

Answer (score 1):

If none of the other posts in this thread work, and you don't want to spend a lot of time learning the idiosyncrasies of MVC parameter passing, here's a perfectly good workaround. In JavaScript, stringify the list:

```
var jSelected = JSON.stringify(selectedIDs);
```

Then deserialise them in the controller:

```
List<int> iCodes = new List<int>();
int iCode = 0;
string[] sNums = IDs.Trim('[').Trim(']').Split(',');

foreach (string sCode in sNums)
{
    if (int.TryParse(sCode, out iCode))
        iCodes.Add(iCode);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usage:

```
[ArrayOrListParameterAttribute("ids", ",")]
public ActionResult Index(List<string> ids)
{

}
```

Here the code for the ArrayOrListParameterAttribute

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MvcApplication1
{
 public class ArrayOrListParameterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the name of the list or array parameter.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The name of the list or array parameter.</value>
    private string ListOrArrayParameterName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the separator.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The separator.</value>
    private string Separator { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ArrayOrListParameterAttribute"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="listOrArrayParameterName">Name of the list or array parameter.</param>
    public ArrayOrListParameterAttribute(string listOrArrayParameterName) : this(listOrArrayParameterName, ",")
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ArrayOrListParameterAttribute"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="listOrArrayParameterName">Name of the list or array parameter.</param>
    /// <param name="separator">The separator.</param>
    public ArrayOrListParameterAttribute(string listOrArrayParameterName, string separator)
    {
        ListOrArrayParameterName = listOrArrayParameterName;
        Separator = separator;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when [action executing].
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filterContext">The filter context.</param>
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        string separatedValues = filterContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString(ListOrArrayParameterName);
        ParameterInfo[] parameters = filterContext.ActionMethod.GetParameters();

        ParameterInfo searchedParameter = Array.Find(parameters, parameter => parameter.Name == ListOrArrayParameterName);

        if (searchedParameter == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Could not find Parameter '{0}' in action method '{1}'", ListOrArrayParameterName, filterContext.ActionMethod.Name));

        Type arrayOrGenericListType = searchedParameter.ParameterType;

        if (!IsTypeArrayOrIList(arrayOrGenericListType))
            throw new ArgumentException("arrayOrIListType is not an array or a type implementing Ilist or IList<>: " + arrayOrGenericListType);

        filterContext.ActionParameters[ListOrArrayParameterName] = GetArrayOrGenericListInstance(arrayOrGenericListType, separatedValues, Separator);

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Non Public Methods

    private static bool IsTypeArrayOrIList(Type type)
    {
        if (type.IsArray)
            return true;

        return (Array.Exists(type.GetInterfaces(), x => x == typeof(IList) || x == typeof(IList<>)));
    }

    private static object GetArrayOrGenericListInstance(Type arrayOrIListType, string separatedValues, string separator)
    {
        if (separatedValues == null)
            return null;

        if (separator == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("separator");

        if (arrayOrIListType.IsArray)
        {
            Type arrayElementType = arrayOrIListType.GetElementType();
            ArrayList valueList = GetValueList(separatedValues, separator, arrayElementType);

            return valueList.ToArray(arrayElementType);
        }

        Type listElementType = GetListElementType(arrayOrIListType);

        if (listElementType != null)
            return GetGenericIListInstance(arrayOrIListType, GetValueList(separatedValues, separator, listElementType));

        throw new InvalidOperationException("The type could not be handled, this should never happen: " + arrayOrIListType);
    }

    private static Type GetListElementType(Type genericListType)
    {
        Type listElementType = null;

        foreach (Type type in genericListType.GetInterfaces())
        {
            if (type.IsGenericType && type == typeof(IList<>).MakeGenericType(type.GetGenericArguments()[0]))
            {
                listElementType = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                break;
            }
        }

        return listElementType;
    }

    private static object GetGenericIListInstance(Type arrayOrIListType, ArrayList valueList)
    {
        object result = Activator.CreateInstance(arrayOrIListType);
        const BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public;

        foreach (object value in valueList)
        {
            arrayOrIListType.InvokeMember("Add", flags, null, result, new[] { value });
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static ArrayList GetValueList(string separatedValues, string separator, Type memberType)
    {
        string[] values = separatedValues.Split(new[] { separator }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        ArrayList valueList = new ArrayList();

        foreach (string value in values)
        {
            valueList.Add(Convert.ChangeType(value, memberType));
        }

        return valueList;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

}

Answer (score -3):

```
 [ArrayOrListParameterAttribute("ids", ",")]
 public ActionResult Index(List<string> ids)
 {

 }
```

Comment: No such attribute.  Not in .NET, and googled and found no source code anywhere.